# File name & Line no when exception occurs

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode, ios

It is getting very hard me to know at which line my code broke as I am using some external framework also.

Is there any way in Xcode using which I can know the line number where exception is coming?

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the line number at all. Just use the stack trace.

Comment: To clarify: If you have the source for the library, set an exception breakpoint ( break on objc_exception_throw() ) and when the exception is thrown, you'll be taken directly to the point of failure (and see the path that led there in the stack trace - useful, since errors often happen upstream of the exception). If you don't have the source for the library there's not a lot of choice as to what to do about it - post a separate question detailing the library, the exception, and your call to the library's method in which the exception occurred. If it's your own code, even better.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: you can set the breakpoint on objc_exception_throw() selecting the Stop on Objective-C Exceptions in Xcode's Run menu.